# read_excel -read hyperlinks from column with also NaN values

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, hyperlink

I found this [instruction](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13439) for reading the links within the one column that contains hyperlinks.

What I have i excel that contains column, that have 2 kinds of values: NaN or Link with: text and hyperlink. Example:

```
NaN
NaN
NaN
Link_text_1:www.something...
Link_text_2:www.something_else...
NaN
```

When I load the excel file, it return only the Text from column and hyperlink is removed.

I tried special instructions, but they do not work.

Base of my code is:

```
path=r'path_to_file'
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='docs')
link_column = df[["Unnamed: 18"]]
print(link_column)
```

And then I will see NaN or Link_text.

I tried:

```
df_2 = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Jobs', converters={"Unnamed: 18": lambda x: str(x.value) + "|"+ str(x.hyperlink.target)})
```

But it return error:

```
df_2 = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Jobs', converters={"Unnamed: 18": lambda x: str(x.value) + "|"+ str(x.hyperlink.target)}) # read sheet Jobs from excel file
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I have tried to google this error but I could not find something that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that pandas is capable of parsing Excel hyperlinks.

So, as a workaround, you can use [**`openpyxl.worksheet.hyperlink`**](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.hyperlink.html) module to get a list of the hyperlinks in a worksheet/column then create a series in your dataframe based on this list.

Try this :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

list_of_links = []
for i in range(2, ws.max_row + 1):
    try:
        list_of_links.append(ws.cell(row=i, column=1).hyperlink.target)
    except AttributeError:
        list_of_links.append(np.nan)
        
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df['Links'] = list_of_links
```

##### # Output:

```
print(df)

          ColA                          Links
0          NaN                            NaN
1          NaN                            NaN
2          NaN                            NaN
3  Link_text_1       http://www.something.../
4  Link_text_2  http://www.something_else.../
5          NaN                            NaN
```

##### # Worksheet used :

[image]